# My php code can't select mysql auto_increment value

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, auto-increment

```
function shopView(){
        global $core;
        $shop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY id DESC");
        $return = '<article>';
        if($shop){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($shop)) {
            $return .= '<h4>'.$row['nazwa'].'</h4><a href="index.php?view=buy&service='.$row['id'].'" class="button">Kup za '.$row['koszt'].' zl (+vat)</a>';
            }
        }
        else{
            $return .= 'Niestety coś poszło nie tak ;/';
        }
        $return .= '</article>';
        return $return;
    }
```

I don't know why this `$row['id']` doesn't work. I have some similar code and there is same code like `?value='.$query['auto_increment'].'`, and there everything is ok. Can somebody help me?

Comment: @Baldrs What about talking in English on this English Q&A.

Comment: Dzięki Baldrs ;). But for example in other source there is `$zapytanie = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shity WHERE czeka='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $l1,$l2"); //wybiera tabelę i pobiera z niej wszystkie dane

if ($zapytanie) {  //jeśli zapytanie można wykonać to...
 while ($shit = mysql_fetch_array($zapytanie)) { //robi pętlę i przypisuje wszystkie dane do zmiennej
  if($shit['typ']=='obrazek') {
 echo '<div id="shit"><a href="obrazek.php?'.$shit['id'].'">...` and everythink is ok ;/

Comment: @OP Check the manual. There is a [function for that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). And while you are it it note the red warning box on that page

Comment: what specifically doesn't work? Do you get php/mysql errors. At first glance your code looks valid..

Comment: @MichałPoreda use pastebin to insert snippets of code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GMxsyjK8 this is pastebin to my function and another code. My function returns <a href="index.php?view=buy&service=" without service value (service=1)

Answer (score 2):

use the following code

```
function shopView(){
    global $core;
    $shop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY id DESC");
    $return = '<article>';
    if($shop){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($shop,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $return .= '<h4>'.$row['nazwa'].'</h4><a href="index.php?view=buy&service='.$row['id'].'" class="button">Kup za '.$row['koszt'].' zl (+vat)</a>';
        }
    }
    else{
        $return .= 'Niestety coś poszło nie tak ;/';
    }
    $return .= '</article>';
    return $return;
}
```

referencess 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php